# Textarea not updating longtext data field

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a simple form with a textarea. I just want to be able to update a longtext data cell in my database when I save and post to the same page. For some reason, the page just doesn't update the database and I can't figure out why.

I don't get any PHP errors and if I simply echo the content on POST of the page, it displays fine.

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="">
<tr>
    <td><textarea name="homeContentText" value="" rows="15" cols="130"><?php echo $homeContent; ?></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Update Content" /></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
include("./admin-connection.php");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE page_content SET content='$_POST[homeContentText]' WHERE page_name='home'");
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your form ? Make sure that `POST` is used in form.

Comment: cannt figure out error from this code .. can you post some more relevant code ..

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST);` ...

Comment: is $con defined anywhere?? in an include...or above at least?

Comment: Use MySQLi in a [prepare-bind-execute style](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)...

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($_POST['homeContentText'])) {   
   mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE page_content SET content='{$_POST['homeContentText']}' WHERE page_name='home'");
}
```

Comment: Change `{$_POST['homeContentText']}` to `{mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['homeContentText'])}`

Comment: On POST of the page I got this error - Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string.

Comment: Can you show `include("./admin-connection.php");` code in your question?

Comment: All the file has is the connection to the database. So $con = mysqli_connect("SERVER", "USERNAME", "PASS", "DB");